# Finding values that make a series convergent

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

So I was given the following prompt:

> When $x=−2$, for what values of p does the series converge?
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-3)^n}{5^n\cdot n^p}\right)$$

I ended up working out this problem to find out that it's convergent for all values of $p$ greater than or equal to $2$, but I'm a bit confused about how to show this. I'm also confused over whether or not this would be an alternating series, since more often than not the $-1$ in the numerator has been indicative of an alternating series. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

For $x = -2$, the proposed series reduces to
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(-5)^{n}}{5^{n}n^{p}} & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{n}5^{n}}{5^{n}n^{p}} = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p}}
\end{align*}

which is known as $p$-series.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

It diverges for $p=1$ (harmonic series).

It simplifies to $-1\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n^p}$.  So it converges for $p\gt1$ (p-series).